# Give value to input box from HttpGet in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, http-get, viewbag

I am trying to set the value of an input box so I can access it from other functions. I want to do this without the use of ViewBag, because I am unable to get valuable information from it.

I have tried using jQuery to access the value and pass it to the controller, but it comes back null. I have also used TempData, but it is not useful if they direct away from the page, and then direct back to it because by then it will be 0. I want to access the id from the Index function in my Search function, how can I accomplish this? Thank you for your time!

View:

```
<div>
    @model MyApp.Models.AboutModel
    <label>Country:</label>
    <input value="@ViewBag.country" /> //this populates with information from my Country Model
    <input asp-controller="AboutPage" asp-action="Search" type="submit" id="btnSearch" />
</div>
```

Country:

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Route("/AboutPage/Index/id")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
        {
            int countryID = id;
            string countryName = "";
            var data = _db.CountryModel.Where(x => x.ID == id).First();
            countryName = data.CountryName;
            ViewBag.country = countryName;
         
            var query = "select * from table where ID = countryID"

            return View(await query);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search(int id)
        {
            //access the id 
        }
```

** Added information: My view is pulling from the model AboutModel, but I am getting this id from CountryModel. I cannot call @Model.id in my view because it will return the wrong ID.

Comment: Hi, how will u call Search action, in view ? If so, u can pass id to view in Index, then use 'asp-id' to Search.

Comment: @MichelleWang thank you for your response. I'm not familiar with 'asp-id'. asp-route-id is not even an option for me with intellisense. I could pass my id variable to it if that's an option. Please give me more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> I want to access the id from the Index function in my Search function

According to your comment, I pass the parameter via `@Model.Id` according to your statement, please refer this code:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
[Route("/AboutPage/Index/id")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
    int countryID = id;
    string countryName = "";
    var data = _db.CountryModel.Where(x => x.ID == id).First();
    countryName = data.CountryName ;
    ViewBag.country = countryName;

    var query = await  _db.AboutModel.Where(x => x.ID == countryID).FirstAsync();
    return View(query);
}
```

View:

```
    @model MyApp.Models.AboutModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index1";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <h1>Index</h1>
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input value="@ViewBag.country" /> //this populates with information from my Country Model
        <input asp-controller="AboutPage" asp-action="Search" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" type="submit" id="btnSearch" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I added a few more details to my question. It gets a little tricky because I am pulling the id from a different model than the one in the view. Also, my return View() inside of my Index is already awaiting a query variable, so adding another argument doesn't work. return View(await query).

Comment: @BeeSwift,  does your Index return one data or multiple datas? In fact, I don’t understand why using `@Model.id` will get the wrong ID. First of all, in your index code, you assign the id to countryID and filter the data of the table through countryID to return to the view, then after filtering at this time ,the ID of the data must be equal to countryID, then it is equal to id.

Comment: You're right. That was my mistake. I was able to get the ID now. Thank you.

Comment: @BeeSwift, ok, I have updated my answer according to your thoughts. If this is valid, please accept it as an answer. This will help people who has the same problem to find the answer more easier.